# Access Database exceeds 5000 items and doesn't function in SharePoint because of that

Tags: database, microsoft-access

I have a table in Microsoft Access that contains much more then 5000 items. In addition, I created a MS access form which I published in SharePoint. In this form, the users have to select some options and at the end a filtered table will be returned.

On the server it works with no issues. But when I try to generate the filtered table on SharePoint, the message "Failed to retrieve list data" appears. It's because the table contains more then 5000 items. When I reduce the amount of items, it works.

Ironically with the use of my filters, the user should never get a result with more then 1500 items. But because the database has in total more than 5000, it doesn't allow to filter the table to begin with.

Is there a way to solve this problem?